# Summation of Number of Digits

Tags: summation

I have seen this problem a while ago and I wasn't able to find the answer.

$$
\begin{align*} 
P_n & = nd(7^n) \\
S & = \sum_{n=1}^{3981} P_n
\end{align*}
$$

Where $nd(n)$ is the number of digits of $n$, such that:
$$
\begin{align*} 
nd&(5) & = 1 \\
nd&(10) & = 2 \\
nd&(5123) & = 4
\end{align*} 
$$

How to find the value of $S$ without use of a computer/calculator?

I could expand $P_n$ as
$$\lfloor n\log_{10}7\rfloor + 1$$
but then I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Have you looked for a pattern in the number of digits in a number of the form $7^n$?

Comment: the answer I got was $6697021$, but that was with a computer...

Comment: @recursive: "Have you looked for a pattern...": Have _you_ looked for a pattern?

Comment: The real exact answer seems to be $6\,700\,385$. Gaffney's estimate (with the $3981/2$ correction term) approximates this as $6\,700\,382$. Not a bad approximation, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.  I don't know what the application is, so it may not be ideal.  If you take the greatest integer signs off of your expression for $P_n$, then sum, you will get:

$$
3981+\log_{10} 7\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{3981}n=3981+\left(\log_{10} 7\right)(3981)(3982)/2
$$

Since we're not taking greatest integers, this will over-estimate the real answer, by pretty close to $3981/2$.  If you subtract that off, you should be within a few numbers of the answer.

Comment: Similarly, you could count the number of "heptal digits" in each number (which is just $n + 1$), take the sum, and scale by $\log_{10} 7$ to get an estimate.